# PHP/MySQL > Count number of obscureness of many strings in table and output an array?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I was wondering if someone could help me simplify my current counting method. I´m trying to learn more in PHP/MySQL so please be positive :)

I have a table with multiple articles that are categorized into sections. What I would like to do is count the number of articles in each section and be able to call that value to be displayed on my web page.

This is my current solution (simplified version without extra query filters) but I would think it fairly resource heavy for a simple task:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT category FROM table");
$list = "";

while($item = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) {
     $list = $list.",".$item['category'];
}
// Then to count how many results for each category:
$categoryA = substr_count($list, 'Category A');
$categoryB = substr_count($list, 'Category B');
...
```

I have about 20 categories that are counted in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table GROUP BY category
```

You can then use this PHP code to get the data in the same format you wanted it.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table GROUP BY category");
$list = array();

while($item = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     $list[$item['category']] = $item['num'];
}

$categoryA = $list['Category A'];
$categoryB = $list['Category B'];
```

Comment: it seems you forgot something :)

Comment: I probably did, its been one of those days.  Mind elaborating?  I am not seeing it at the moment.

Comment: I've just added category to your query. otherwise it seems quite useless

Comment: That was already on there.  I missed it at first and edited a few seconds later before your comment.  I wonder why it was not showing up for you.  I also don't see any edit history from you.

Comment: Thanks, I´ll try that. on my first try I got no results (by just replacing my query with yours). But when I get home I can give it a better try :)

Comment: For some reason I´m not getting all the results from this query. My original query gave me a full comma separated list.

The suggested query gives just about 1/3 of results needed.

Comment: Using this query with `GROUP BY` will combine all results from a given category into a single row with a number.  The number is the number of rows that had that category.  So although you get fewer rows, the number of rows in each category is already calculated for you.

Comment: I see, if I could get some help with printing out the correct amount of how many times each category is listed, then my problem is solved :) What ever I´m doing I just get part of the results.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the PHP code that will get it in the same format you were trying to get.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. What you posted makes sense, but for some reason I get: 'syntax error, unexpected '[' in /public_html/index.php on line 14'

Comment: Where line 14 is $list[$item['category']] = item['num'];. The unexpected bracket is the "$list[" bracket.

Comment: It was actually the item[ bracket.  I missed the `$` before `item`.  I updated the answer.